# How to convert $y²=2x-x²$ into $x=f(y)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

My problem is to convert the expression $y=\sqrt{2x-x²}$ into $x=f(y)$ format. I get rid of the square root, but then what?

Comment: Hint: Complete the square on $x$.

Comment: Move all terms on one side.  What do you get?  A quadratic in terms of x with a constant that depends on y equal to zero.  You are solving for x.  How do you solve quadratics?   Can you go on from there?  If you used the quadradic formula you let a= 1, b = -2,  and c = y^2

Comment: Thank you, YoTengo, you hint helped me to solve this. If you would like to write your hint in the form of an answer, I am going to accept it.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help. Problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$y^2=2x-x^2$$
$$(1)x^2+(-2)x+(y^2)=0$$
$$\begin{align}
x&=\frac{-(-2)\pm\sqrt{(-2)^2-4(1)(y^2)}}{2(1)} \\[2 ex]
 &=\frac{2\pm\sqrt{4-4y^2}}{2} \\[2 ex]
 &=1\pm\sqrt{1-y^2}
\end{align}$$

Not that the plus-or-minus gives you *two* expressions for $x$. This is needed since your original equation does not define a one-to-one function of $x$, even if you replace the $y^2$ with $y$. Therefore if $|y|=1$ there is only one value of $x$, but for $|y|<1$ there are two possible values of $x$. And of course, if $|y|>1$ there is no possible value of $x$.

Comment: @Arthur: Why did you delete your answer? It was a perfectly good one, using a different method than my answer. (Completing the square vs. the quadratic formula.)