# How to convert an equation from y = f(x) to x = f(y) while completing the square?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I completed the square and ended up with this equation below and do not know what to do next.
$$
Y = \frac{(X - 2)^2}{2} + 1 
$$

I found this answer: [How to convert $y²=2x-x²$ into $x=f(y)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1530547/how-to-convert-y%c2%b2-2x-x%c2%b2-into-x-fy) which shows how to solve with the quadratic equation but the only answer there is how to solve with the quadratic equation.

Comment: Seems to be straightforward manipulation. EG $2Y - 2 = (X-2)^2$, then take square roots and add 2 to both sides.

Comment: Here's the catch when you go to invert the relationship: For many values of $Y$, there are $2$ distinct values of $X$ that produce that $Y$. That's okay when you go $X \mapsto Y$. But if you want to invert it, and go $Y \mapsto X$, you will have to make a choice: which $X$? This amounts to the choice of $\pm$ the square root.

Comment: Ah ok thanks. I had to go review my order of operations, it's been a long time since I did maths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $Y=\frac{(X-2)^2}{2}+1$ then $2Y-2=(X-2)^2$. By taking the square root of both sides $X=\pm\sqrt{2Y-2}+2$. To make sure that this is indeed correct we look at
$$\left(\frac{(X-2)^2}{2}+1\right)\bigg|_{X=\pm\sqrt{2Y-2}+2}=\frac{(\pm\sqrt{2Y-2}+2-2)^2}{2}+1=Y-1+1=Y.$$